# Child selector problem in IE7, IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I have a CSS style using child selectors in an HTML page as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>MSO Bug</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
            ol{list-style-type:decimal;}
            ol > ol {list-style-type:lower-alpha;}
            ol > ol >ol {list-style-type:lower-roman;}
        </style>    

    </head>
    <body>

     <div>
     <ol>
        <li><div>level1</div></li>
        <ol>
            <li><div>level2</div></li>
            <ol>
                <li><div>level3</div></li>
            </ol>
        </ol>
     </ol>

      </div>               
    </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, the CSS works properly - the first list level starts with '1', the second with 'a', and the third with 'i' as expected.

But this doesn't work in IE7/8!

(I'm aware of descendent selectors - for some reason I can't use that here)

Comment: MatW - I get all list bullets as '1'. Edited to include the whole page.

Comment: have you tried without the whitespace between the selectors ? `ol>ol` instead of `ol > ol` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always set `list-style` and `list-style-type` properties to the `ul` (not the `li`).

```
ol { list-style-type: decimal; }
ol > li > ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }
ol > li > ol > li > ol { list-style-type: lower-roman; }
```

**Update:** Now that you’ve added the HTML to your question, it looks like a couple of things are wrong:

1. You’re not declaring a doctype. Try adding `<!doctype html>` above the first line of your code.
2. Your HTML for your main `OL` is invalid. You’re closing the `LI` elements too early. An `OL` element can’t have another `OL` as a direct child element. This is what it should look like:

   ```
   <ol>
    <li>
     <div>level1</div>
      <ol>
       <li>
        <div>level2</div>
        <ol>
         <li>
          <div>level3</div>
         </li>
        </ol>
       </li>
      </ol>
     </ol>
    </li>
   </ol>
   ```

Comment: +1 to that Mathias. I fixed that basic error, and edited the post to include the complete page. Still doesn't work in IE7 (and continues to work in FF).

Comment: You're right. It's a combination of both the errors you've mentioned. Accepting your answer. Unfortunately, many RTF editors produce code such as the one I've given (e.g. the YUI editor).

Need to find a workaround...

Thanks nevertheless!

Comment: I'm confused that this answer works! Your CSS shouldn't work now, as the ol's are no longer directly related...

Comment: MatW - this doesn't actually work! Please see my comment above. However the explanation given by Mathias is the correct one, hence I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 12):

You need to specify a DOCTYPE for child descendants to work in IE7 / 8.

HTML 4.01 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

HTML 4.01 Transitional:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">>
```

HTML 4.01 Frameset:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Without the DOCTYPE, IE reverts to quirks mode and will only support descendant selectors, not child selectors.

Comment: I tried all three above by adding them before the <html>. None of them caused the CSS to work. How do I know which mode IE is in?

Comment: It should do; the error has nothing to do with putting <ol> in <li>... The above code is tested and works.

Comment: @Mathias Bynens. Sure, but the point is that the incorrect HTML isn't the problem, it's the lack of DOCTYPE. Incorrect HTML does confuse the issue though, so I'll rollback.

Comment: @Raj You can use javascript to find out what mode IE is in; "alert(document.compatMode);". It will say "BackCompat" if you're in quirks mode (bad), "CSS1Compat" if you're not (good).

Comment: Thanks MatW, that's useful info